gtsummary inline_text(), use of column by name
I am creating an table by tbl_summary and use inline_text(), to use the results.
Since an update using the colnames doesn't work, I am required to use "stat_1" instead.
However, when I print the whole table, it shows the labels correctly.
Has anyone an idea, why inline_text changed behavior?
Are there any requirements for an factor to be used in inline_text?
I went through the documentation and google and didn't find a clue.
Thanks for your help
Minmal reproducible example:
    Children2 <- tibble(
      "MTS_specific" = as_factor(sample(c("specific","nonspecific"), 100,T)),
      "Age_INT" = sample(1:18, 100,T),
      "Geschlecht_FCT" = as_factor(sample(c("male","female"), 100,T)),
      "AK_Entl_DT" =sample(1:180, 100,T)
    )

    results2 <- Children2 |>
      select("Diagramm" = MTS_specific, AK_Entl_DT, Age_INT, "Gender"=Geschlecht_FCT) |>
      tbl_summary(by="Diagramm",
              )
    #This works:
    inline_text(results2, variable = "Age_INT", column = "stat_1", pattern= "{median}")

    #This used to work (and is desired, again)
    inline_text(results2, variable = "Age_INT", column = "nonspecific", pattern= "{median}")


This looks like a bug to me in gtsummary 2.0.0. According to the docs it should still be possible to pass a level from the by column. And actually the example in the docs work fine. After some experimenting the issue only seems to arise if the by column is a factor whereas the code works fine after coercing to a character.

Thanks für the help!
Converting to a character also works in my hands.
Does it make sense to contact the authors of gtsummary if we suspect a bug?

Yeah. Filing an issue would be much appreciated by the authors: https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues. And if you do so it would be nice if you add a comment with a the link to the issue as a reference.

Alright, done!
https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1883
Thanks again an have a good evening!
